# what is the best way to register a new user - get vs post

Tags: javascript, python, api, rest, fastapi

i'm trying to learn best practices for registering new users.

I can only think of two options (but maybe there are more!) and am hoping to know which is better for speed, and for overall practice:

**first method:**

```
a. once the user submits a new user&pass, i make a GET request on a REST entrypoint
b. if the user exists then let him know, if not then make a POST request
```

**second method:**

```
a. once the user submits a new user&pass, i make a POST request, within which a GET request is made.
b. if the user exists then let him know, if not then continue with the POST
```

also, should these be done within one entry point - go back to the client, and then have js do another call

thanks

Comment: Are you creating your own backend??

Comment: @NishantBhosale yes, the back end is a fastapi app that call on a postgres db

Comment: what does it mean, GET within POST?
generally, POST should be the way, and nothings stops you from responding to a POST request with registration status just as you would to GET

Comment: Just do a POST, if the user already exists return a `409 Conflict` or `406 Not Acceptable`, or something like that.

Comment: @YuriSh i previously had a POST entry point, which at the end of the function made another post request using requests.Session() in order to make a second entry in a db that required a primary key to first exist- so i thought i'd do something similar to check if a user exists

Comment: @iScripters got it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better having only one POST request, that return a 409(conflict) status if the user already exists, and a 201(resource created) status if the user was successfully created.